# Set environment variable on Ansible

Tags: ansible

I would like to set (and persist) an environment variable from an ansible playbook. I wrote:

```
# Set the JVM ram
- name: Set the JVM ram
  environment:
    ES_HEAP_SIZE: 2g
```

However, I get:

> ERROR: 'action' or 'local_action' attribute missing in task "Set the
>   JVM ram"

Answer (score 2):

The `environment` tag is not an task, but an attribute that can be applied to individual tasks or applied globally.  Per the [ansible FAQ](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/faq.html) what you want to do is just specify something like this at the top of your playbook:

```
---

environment:
    ES_HEAP_SIZE: 2g
```

Note that this is different from what you specified because `- name` specifies the start of an individual task, where the example above is just defining a dict at the top level, which ansible interprets and applies as environment variables before processing tasks.

Answer (score 2):

You’ve got the right idea. But you’re missing your “action”; every task needs one. Your `environment` setting will work/apply if you do this (but only for this task):

```
# Set the JVM ram
- name: Set the JVM ram
  command: ./bin/elasticsearch  # now using envvar instead of -Xmx10g -Xms10g 
  environment:
    ES_HEAP_SIZE: 2g
  # OR
  #environment: {ES_HEAP_SIZE: 2g}
```

Comment: elasticsearch is defined as system service. I cannot launch it like that.

Comment: That's fine. I just put that in as an example command. You must have something to run. Or, you could have the task be a `lineinfile` that puts it into an rc/environment file.